# Stripe Webhook signature verification error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm developing a webhook in my firebase to receveive updates for completed checkouts, the only problem is that it doesn't works, Stripe keeps getting back a 500 response with an empty error body, here is the code:

//index.js

```
const webHooks = express();

PaymentController.prototype.bindWebHookEndpoints(webHooks);
exports.webhook = functions.region(REGION).https.onRequest(webHooks);
```

//PaymentController.js

```
bindWebHookEndpoints(app) {
    /**
     * Endpoint to receive payments status updates.
     */
    app.post("/payments", express.raw({type: "application/json"}), (request, response) => {
      const signature = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
      console.log({rawBody: request.rawBody});
      return PaymentSystemRemoteService.prototype.postWebHookValidationAsync(request.rawBody.toString(), signature).then((event)=>{
        functions.logger.log({event: event});
        switch (event.type) {
          case "checkout.session.async_payment_failed":

            // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.async_payment_failed
            break;
          case "checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded":

            // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded
            break;
          case "checkout.session.completed":

            // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.completed
            break;

          default:
            console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
        }
        response.status(200).send({});
      }).catch((err)=>{
        functions.logger.log({err: err});
        response.status(500).send(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

//PaymentSystemRemoteService.js

```
const endpointSecret = "whsec_..."; (Got from the stripe dev portal)


  postWebHookValidationAsync(body, signature) {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
      return stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, signature, endpointSecret).then((event)=>{
        return res(event);
      }).catch((err)=>{
        return rej(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Any hints? thanks!

Comment: I'd probably start by adding some logs to check the values of things like `body`, `signature` and directly compare them to the Stripe event in the dashboard. Note there is whitespace in the event Stripe sends which needs to be preserved

Comment: Why don't you use a simple [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)?

Comment: Along with the above suggestions ,you may check these out : [Unable to send data from stripe webhook to firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68501067/unable-to-send-data-from-stripe-webhook-to-firebase)[Stripe checkout webhook not passing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579146/stripe-checkout-webhook-not-passing-customer-email)[Stripe webhook function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131073/why-my-stripe-webhook-function-is-not-workingtest-mode)

Comment: Guys I've tryed practically everything, still nothing, rawBody is indeed defined but I keep getting an empty error message, I've reached out stripe support, let's see...

Comment: Check out, https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/stripe